# Function with string explanation for its arguments with equal signs

Tags: functions, function-construction, programming

I want to write a function using string as explanation for its arguments so that the function becomes intuitive for new users. For example, I want to write a function to compute BMI (just for illustration, not the real problem):

```
bmi[h_, w_] := (703*w)/(12*h)^2
bmi[5.4, 142]
```

> 23.7735

I can modify this function as the following and it works but assigns values.

```
bmi2[heightinFeet = h_, weightinLB = w_] := (703*w)/(12*h)^2
bmi2[5.4, 142] == bmi2[heightinFeet = 5.4, weightinLB = 142]
bmi2[heightinFeet = 5.4, weightinLB = 142]
heightinFeet
```

> True
>
> 23.7735
>
> 5.4

But I want to define the function with explanation of the arguments without assignment. That is, I want to modify this function as follows and not assign values:

```
bmi3["height in Feet" = h_, "weight in LB" = w_] := (703*w)/(12*h)^2
bmi3[5.4, 142]
```

> 23.7735

I guess `bmi3` might work but not sure how this assignment is working. Is there a better way to address this issue?

Comment: if it is ok to use `Rule` instead of `Set`, you can do `bmi0[("height in Feet" -> h_) | (h_), ("weight in LB" ->    w_) | (w_)] := (703*w)/(12*h)^2`

Comment: @ Roman, there might be misunderstanding regarding my question and what I want to accomplish. I have edited the question to reflect what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.  By overriding the action of `Set`/`=` by making `bmi3` have the `Attribute` `HoldAll`, we can take apart the arguments before `Set` is executed:

```
ClearAll[bmi3];
SetAttributes[bmi3, HoldAll]; 
bmi3[("heightinFeet" = h_) | h_, ("weightinLB" = w_) | w_] := 
 With[{map = {"heightinFeet" -> h, "weightinLB" -> w}},
  ((703*"weightinLB")/(12*"heightinFeet")^2 /. map)];

bmi3["heightinFeet" = 5.4, "weightinLB" = 142]
(*  23.7735  *)

bmi3[5.4, "weightinLB" = 142]
(*  23.7735  *)

bmi3[5.4, 142]
(*  23.7735  *)
```

A more *Mathematica*-like way would be to use options, somewhat like @kglr's suggestion in a comment:

```
ClearAll[bmi];
Options[bmi] = {"heightinFeet" -> $Failed, "weightinLB" -> $Failed};
bmi::hw = "Specify both \"heightinFeet\" and \"weightinLB\".";
bmi[OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{map = Thread[{"heightinFeet", "weightinLB"} -> 
       OptionValue[{"heightinFeet", "weightinLB"}]]},
   ((703*"weightinLB")/(12*"heightinFeet")^2 /. map) /; 
    FreeQ[map, $Failed]
   ];
bmi[___] := Message[bmi::hw];
```

Now the order doesn't matter:

```
bmi["heightinFeet" -> 5.4, "weightinLB" -> 142]
(*  23.7735  *)

bmi["weightinLB" -> 142, "heightinFeet" -> 5.4]
(*  23.7735  *)

bmi["heightinFeet" -> 5.4]
```

> bmi::hw: Specify both "heightinFeet" and "weightinLB".

If you want to also have `bmi[h, w]`, insert this definition after the definition of `bmi::hw`:

```
bmi[h : Except[_Rule | _RuleDelayed], w : Except[_Rule | _RuleDelayed]] := 
  bmi["heightinFeet" -> h, "weightinLB" -> w];
```

In this definition, order matters, however.  If you want to restrict this form to numeric inputs, then use this definition instead:

```
bmi[h_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] := bmi["heightinFeet" -> h, "weightinLB" -> w];
```

Comment: @ Michael, thank you for your answer. My goal is to introduce user defined functions to new users. Therefore, making function arguments intuitive is a primary goal.  Your answer provides an additional help for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Michael E2's way of using options is a neat way if you have to handle many arguments and if you can specify good default values for them. If the user is always forced to enter all options, then this becomes very clunky, (and the options are not optional anymore!).

Think of

```
Sin["Angle" -> Pi/3]
```

vs.

```
Sin[Pi/3]
```

So, for that few number of variables that are all mandatory, the classical thing to do is to write a short *documentation* of `bmi`, e.g.,

```
bmi::usage = "bmi[h,w] compute the body masss index for a person of height h and weight w."
```

Then the user can learn about `bmi` by executing

```
?bmi
```

Comment: @ Henrik, thank you.

Comment: @ramesh, you're welcome.